# AngularJS, combine these two methods into one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div

```
<div id="slideHolder" ng-mouseenter="fadeIn()" ng-mouseleave="fadeOut()">
...
</div>
```

And the content in the middle fades in an out on mouseenter/leave

```
$scope.fadeIn = function()
{
    TweenLite.to("#zoomInButton",0.3,{opacity:1});  
}

$scope.fadeOut = function()
{
    TweenLite.to("#zoomInButton",0.3,{opacity:0});  
}
```

Is it possible combine those two functions into one using an `if statement` ? I know how I'd do it in `jQuery`, but not sure how to in `Angular`. Thanks

Edit:
This is how I did it in jQuery

```
$("#slideHolder").hover(
    function() {
        $("#zoomButton").stop(true,true).fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
        $("#zoomButton").stop(true,true).fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Granted they are technically two function still, I was able to shorthand them into the hover method

Comment: Can you show how you'd do it in jQuery and why you don't think this would work in Angular?

Comment: I added the jquery hover method. Basically the way I see it happening is something like: `function hover() { (event.mouseenter) ? //fadeIn : //fadeOut; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out

```
<div id="slideHolder" ng-mouseenter="fade($event)" ng-mouseleave="fade($event)">
....
</div>
```

and in angular

```
$scope.fade = function(event)
{
  (event.type == 'mouseover') ? TweenLite.to("#zoomInButton",0.3,{opacity:1}) : TweenLite.to("#zoomInButton",0.3,{opacity:0});  
}
```